# Pulsar 180 - How Can I Measure the Mileage?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-consumption

Could anybody please tell me how to measure the mileage of my Pulsar 180 bike accurately?  I have tried by emptying my tank.  I failed miserably, and I had to take my bike walking long distance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I said [over here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3394/57), mileage calculations are pretty easy:

1. Fill your tank.
2. Drive a well-known standard route. For example, my commute is almost always the same from day to day.
3. Drive to gas station and re-fill the tank. Note amount filled and cost.
4. Take the total miles driven from steps 1 - 3 and divide by the number of gallons filled in step 3. That's your miles per gallon (bigger is better).
5. Take the total miles driven from steps 1 - 3 and divide by the cash paid in step 3. That's your miles per dollar (bigger is better).
6. Repeat steps 1-5 until you feel like you have a good data set.

Comment: Preferably use the same gas station during your test

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple idea.

1. Drive till you hit reserve then reset your trip (you need not fill petrol
   immediately while reserve).
2. Fill petrol and note the price and quantity and turn the knob from
   reserve to main position.
3. When you hit the next reserve check the distance travelled in the trip meter and divide the number with the quantity of petrol you filled.

Comment: This method is very accurate. This way the exact amount of distance traveled is divided by the exact amount of fuel consumed. This is of course specific to the pulsar 180 vehicles that have a fuel cock that has a reserve level.

Comment: I agree with chilljeet , this answer is much more relevant in case of a pulsar 180.

Comment: this answer usefull for vehicles have reserve knob/indicator